# Cocos2dx NDK build error on android studio

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have following error when i try to build my game on android studio:

```
Error:(81) Android NDK: Application targets deprecated ABI(s): armeabi    
Error:(82) Android NDK: Support for these ABIs will be removed in a future NDK release.
```

Run from command line works fine:

```
cocos run . -p android --android-studio
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android.mk and change `APP_ABI` from `armeabi` to `armeabi-v7a`.

If you are using CMakeLists to build your project then go to `gradle.properties` and change to `PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a` if you want to add more architectures follow the instructions located in the `gradle.properties` file.